# Why overriding Spree default styles is inconsistent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, spree

I am making an SCSS override file for the default Spree template.  On the product catalogue display page there is a border around each product image.  If I change the border properties for the base state of the `product-image` class, nothing changes.  However if I add an alteration for `product-image:hover` it works without an issue.

I can resolve the problem using `!important` but I'd be grateful to understand why the change doesn't go through without that, despite the :hover state changing.

Comment: Your style likely isn't taking effect due to something with a higher CSS priority specifying a different style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selectors have different specificity value. It affects overriding priority:

From spec:

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a) count the
>   number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in
>   the selector (= b) count the number of type selectors and
>   pseudo-elements in the selector (= c) ignore the universal selector
>   Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other,
>   but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large
>   base) gives the specificity.

Example:

```css
*               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
#x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
#s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
```

**You can calculate selector Specificity with [this tool](http://specificity.keegan.st/)**

Comment: That appears to have hit the nail on the head, thank you very much indeed.  Had no idea that the number of elements would have an effect on priority.

Comment: @TheMinimalCriminal It makes sense because you can specify behavior for all elements of certain group and override it by referring the most specific ones. For example: "All cats(Species) have fur. Sphynxes(breed) don't. "